# Exception, for element not found?

Tags: scrapy

If during crawling, scrapy is unable to find a node and extract data from it? will it throw an exception and close the **scraper**? Or, just store a null value for that item's attribute?

I am asking this because, I was wondering whether or not, I should check for element existence, before extraction using if statements.

Comment: I am yet to observe scrapy's behavior. I tried selenium Web Driver, and it wasn't serving my purpose, it used to throw ElementNotFoundException. So, I am switching over to Scrapy, So, I am asking this, hoping people who have used Scrapy, can help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `try` statement to handle exceptions so if it doesn't find what you need it will move along. This also works in Selenium.

If you don't treat exceptions in your code the script will stop but in scrapy's case if made requests before, only the thread where the exception was found will stop and the rest will keep going.